# How do I remove the delay between HTTP Requests when using Asynchronous actions in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am using HttpClient to send a GET request to a server inside of a while loop

```
while (cycle < maxcycle)
{

    var searchParameters = new ASearchParameters
    {
        Page = cycle++,
        id = getid
    };

    var searchResponse = await Client.SearchAsync(searchParameters);

}
```

and the SearchAsync contains

```
public async Task<AuctionResponse> SearchAsync()
{
    
    var uriString = "Contains a https url with parameters"
    var searchResponseMessage = await HttpClient.GetAsync(uriString);

    return await Deserialize<AuctionResponse>(searchResponseMessage);

    
}
```

The thing is after every request there is a delay before the next request is started.
you can see this in fiddler timeline and also in fiddler there is "Tunnel To" example.com:443 before every request

[image]

### **Question : Why is there a delay and how to remove it ?**

Comment: Here's some info on why you are seeing "Tunnel To" in Fiddler, and what it means: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/httpfiddler/RCkzE3HhhxY.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why are people marking this as a duplicate? This question has *nothing* to do with how best to use await in a loop. It is asking what could be causing a delay between multiple HTTP requests.

Comment: @KevinBabcock Seems like the best thing to do would be to edit the question to make that abundantly clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two things that are happening here. First, depending on the deserializer, it may take a while to translate your response back into an object. You might want to time that step and see if that's not the majority of your time spent. Second, the SSL handshake (the origin of your "tunnel to") does require a round trip to establish the SSL channel. I thought HttpClient sent a Keep-Alive header by default, but you may want to see if it is A) not being sent or B) being rejected. If you are re-establishing an SSL channel for each request, that could easily take on the order of a hundred ms all by itself (depending upon the server/network load).

If you're using Fiddler, you can enable the ability to inspect SSL traffic to see what the actual request/response headers are.

Comment: Those little green dots next to each request in the transfer activity indicate that the connection was re-used for each request. If a new connection was established, the dots would be red.

Comment: OK, good. Then I'd focus on deserialization. If it is indeed deserialization overhead, I would look at using some sort of queue to parallelize the download of data with the deserialization/local processing of the downloaded data.

Comment: Solved it, It was because the HttpClient was re-started before every request :/ my bad. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you see this delay for a couple of reasons. Based on the code you provided, all other actions besides the request itself take up some fraction of the time between requests. So deserializing the response will add to a delay.

Also, the delay might be tied to the amount of data that is being returned and processed further down the stack. I tried to recreate the scenario you describe in your question with the following code:

```
const int MaxNumberOfCycles = 10;

static void Main()
{
    Start().Wait();
}

async Task Start()
{
    var client = new Client();
    var cycle = 0;

    while (cycle < MaxNumberOfCycles)
    {
        var response = await client.SearchAsync(cycle++);
    }
}

class Client
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SearchAsync(int n)
    {
        // parameter 'n' used to vary web service response data
        var url = ... // url removed for privacy
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url))
        {
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

With small response sizes I saw no delay between requests. As response sizes increased I began to see slightly longer delays. Here's a screenshot for a series of requests returning 1MB responses:

[image: fiddler network transfer timeline graph]

One thing I noticed about your scenario is that your transfer activity graph shows a solid black line at the end of each request. This line indicates the "time to first byte", meaning that response processing did not even start until the very end of your request.

Another issue you might consider is that Fiddler is that causing these delays. I noticed that your responses aren't being streamed by Fiddler, which probably impacts the results. You can read more about [response streaming in Fiddler](http://www.webdbg.com/fiddler/help/Streaming.asp).

I hope some of this information helps...

Comment: In your scenario once the response is received the next request is sent immediately, there is no delay between the response and the next request but it happens in my code.